# Power BI - Look up value from another row in same column

Tags: powerbi, dax, row, lookup

I have the following table and want to be able to compare the Current Date with the Old Date via the Linking Key.

| Linking Key | Category | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Current | 12-Apr-23 |
| 111 | Old | 15-Apr-23 |
| 333 | Current | 15-Apr-23 |
| 333 | Old | 16-Apr-23 |

I know how to calculate date differences once I have the Old Date as a calculated column, but how do I get it to the shape below? I know I will have to use the Linking Key, but not sure how. I can't pivot the table as it is also used for other visuals.

| Linking Key | Category | Date | Old Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Current | 12-Apr-23 | 15-Apr-23 |
| 111 | Old | 15-Apr-23 | 15-Apr-23 |
| 333 | Current | 15-Apr-23 | 16-Apr-23 |
| 333 | Old | 16-Apr-23 | 16-Apr-23 |

I would then filter on Current Category in the visual so that there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in M query, group by `Linking Key`, and take `Min(Date)` as `Date` and `Max(Date)` as `Old Date`.

A query should look like this:

```
= Table.Group(#"Your_Table", {"Linking Key"}, {{"Date", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable date}, {"Old Date", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}})
```

You can always use the user interface :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create Lead/Lag columns using M language in Power Query

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjRSitWJVjI2BVNGxmDKxBxMmZqBKXMLMGUBUWJpqBQbCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Number = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Number", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"xyz" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Lead", each #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[#"Number"]),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(xyz, {{"Index", 0}}),
    #"Replaced Errors1" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Replaced Errors", {{"Lead", 0}}),
    #"abc" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Errors1", "Lag", each #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[#"Number"]),
    #"Replaced Errors2" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(abc, {{"Lag", 0}})

in
    #"Replaced Errors2"
```

Check this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNdfs2BRid8